# how to get two strings in an android textbox after a condition is met

Tags: java, android

I am designing a form for an app library. I am trying to get the string " - required" to add onto strings when initially setting up the form.

```
<string name="firstName_label">First Name</string>
<string name="lastName_label">Last Name</string>
<string name="companyName_label">Company Name</string>
<string name="email_label">Email</string>
<string name="address1_label">Address</string>
<string name="address2_label">Address 2</string>
<string name="city_label">City</string>
<string name="stateProvince_label">State/Province</string>
<string name="append_required"> - required</string>
```

are some of my strings, and I have a "requiredfields" for setting their 'flags'

```
<string name="required_fields">firstName,lastName,email,mobilePhone,postalCode</string>
```

My question is how would I able to check against this in the java, as well as combing the 2 strings together (Im guessing a StringBuilder).
I'd like for this to be as generic/universal as possible because this is an app library supporting 15 different apps having different requiredfields.

Comment: To get one of these strings you need something like getResources().getString(R.string.firstName_label)  then you can combine strings

Comment: Yeah, I figured I would use a string Builder and that call you mentioned to combine the strings. That's not really where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Heres what I did:

```
if ((fieldsStr != null) && (fieldsStr.trim().length() > 0)) {
        String[] fields = fieldsStr.split(",");
        for (String field : fields) {
            if (required) {
                int labelID =
                        activity.getResources().getIdentifier(field + "_label", "string",
                                activity.getPackageName());
                StringBuilder hint = new StringBuilder();
                hint.append(activity.getApplicationContext().getString(labelID)).append(
                        " - Required");
                int nameID =
                        activity.getResources().getIdentifier(field, "id",
                                activity.getPackageName());
                EditText v = (EditText)activity.findViewById(nameID);
                v.setHint(hint.toString());
                }
          }
}
```

I used the array of strings to get which one to edit, and modifying the getIdentifier to grab the label as opposed to the ID was the main issue I was having after I figured out what needed to be done (which was @Esteams answer). After that, it was simply just putting the StringBuilder together and pushing it to the EditText.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array to store all the required field ids:

```
private static final int[] mRequiredFields = new int[]{R.string.firstName_label, R.string.lastName_label};
```

Or create an arrays resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="required_fields">
        <item>@string/firstName_label</item>
        <item>@string/lastName_label</item>
        <item>@string/companyName_label</item>
        <item>@string/email_label</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then in the code you could just go through the array like this for the first suggestion:

```
final Resources resources = getResources();
final String stringToAppend = resources.getString(R.string.append_required);
for (int id : requiredFields) {
    String requiredField = resources .getString(id);

    // create your string here

}
```

Or for the second suggestion:

```
    final Resources resources = getResources();
    final String[] requiredFields = resources.getStringArray(R.array.required_fields);
    final String stringToAppend = resources.getString(R.string.append_required);
    for (String requireField : requiredFields) {
        // create your string here
    }
```